Show monthly installment prices on Woocommerce single product page for variable product variations
I am using a plugin to display a widget that calculates the monthly installments of a product when buying on credit. The plugin uses $product->get_price() and $variation->get_price() to fill the data-amount= parameter to auto calculate the installment based on the product price. However it only seems to work correctly on simple products with a static price, on variable products it only calculates the first variation and doesn't change dynamically for each variation when selecting different variables. I suspect that the function for displaying the widget on the variable page (function mobicred_variation_widget_display) is incorrect. Is there a way to update this code so the plugin would calculate and display the installment for variable products correctly for each variation?
Here is the code I currently have:
 function mobicred_widget_display() {

    global $post;
    
    if( function_exists("wc_get_product") ) {
      $product = wc_get_product($post->ID);
    }
    else {
      $product = new WC_Product($post->ID);
    }
    
    $price = $product->get_price();
  
    $thePlugin = new WC_Mobicred_Instalment();

 $widget_code = '<script src="https://mobicred.co.za/plugins/instalment.js"></script>';
    $widget_code .= '<div id="instalmentCalc"';
    $widget_code .= 'data-amount="';
    $widget_code .= $price;
    $widget_code .= '"></div>';

    echo $widget_code;

  }

  add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','mobicred_widget_display',15);

  function mobicred_variation_widget_display( $price, $variation ) {

    $widget_code = $price;

    $amount = $variation->get_price();

    $thePlugin = new WC_Mobicred_Instalment();

    $widget_code .= '<script src="includes/instalment.js"></script>';
    $widget_code .= '<div id="instalmentCalc"';
    $widget_code .= 'data-amount="';
    $widget_code .= $amount;
    $widget_code .= '"></div>';

 echo $widget_code;

  }

  add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_price_html', 'mobicred_variation_widget_display', 10, 2);
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_sale_price_html', 'mobicred_variation_widget_display', 10, 2);



Did you write this code, or is this from an installed plugin? If you didn't write this and it's a 3rd-party plugin, you should ask their developers for a solution. If you update the code in this plugin, and then update the plugin after a new version is released, you will lose your customization.

Hi there, this is a 3rd party plugin I'm using. I have reached out to the developers but they weren't able to help. They said that the plugin will only work on simple products but looking at the code it looks like there was an attempt for it to read from variation prices and that maybe the function is just wrong. So I figured if I could just adjust the code myself I could get it to work the way I need to for variables. I am not exceedingly skilled in php so I could be mistaken.
